# Unknown column 'b.Hostname' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, ansi-sql

I have the following MYSQL Query - trying to join 3 tables and find unique information(data)

```
SELECT a.LocationID, a.Model, a.SerialNum,a.Purpose, b.IP, a.Services,a.DeviceID, COUNT(a.Hostname)
FROM RefConnection.Equipment_Info a, RefConnection.Connections b, RefConnection.VM_Info c
JOIN Equipment_Info on b.Hostname = a.Hostname
WHERE a.Hostname = c.Hostname
  AND b.status = a.Status
  AND a.status = c.Status
GROUP BY a.LocationID, a.Model, a.SerialNum, a.Purpose, b.IP, a.Services, a.DeviceID
ORDER BY COUNT(b.Hostname)DESC;
```

This works with 2 tables :

```
SELECT d.locationID, d.Model, d.SerialNum, d.Status, da.IP, COUNT(d.HOSTNAME)
FROM RefConnection.Equipment_Info d, RefConnection.Connections da
WHERE d.Hostname = da.Hostname
  AND d.Status = da.Status
Group By d.locationID, d.Model, d.locationID, d.Model, d.SerialNum, d.Status, da.IP
ORDER BY COUNT(da.Hostname) DESC;
```

Unknown column 'b.Hostname' in 'on clause'

Comment: RefConnection is your database? Or are you trying to join the table with itself 3 times?

Comment: `JOIN Equipment_Info on b.Hostname = a.Hostname`   What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

```
FROM RefConnection.Equipment_Info a JOIN
     RefConnection.Connections b
     ON b.Hostname = a.Hostname AND
        b.status = a.Status JOIN
     RefConnection.VM_Info c
     ON a.Hostname = c.Hostname AND
        a.status = c.Status
```

Your problem is the scoping rules for identifiers.  This does not work as you expect with commas -- yet another reason to avoid them.

I don't know what `Equipment_Info` is doing a second time in the query.

I would also strongly advise you to use meaningful table aliases, such as `e`, `c`, and `i` rather than arbitrary characters.

Comment: @Gorfon Linoff Hostname, status are all in the 3 tables and Equipment_Info Hostname acts as the primary hostname.

 Select a.LocationID, a.Model, a.SerialNum,a.Purpose, b.IP, a.Services,a.DeviceID, Count(a.Hostname)
FROM RefConnection.Equipment_Info a JOIN
     RefConnection.Connections b
     ON b.Hostname = a.Hostname AND
        b.status = a.Status JOIN
     RefConnection.VM_Info c
     ON a.Hostname = c.Hostname AND
        a.status = c.Status
group by a.LocationID, a.Model, a.SerialNum, a.Purpose, b.IP, a.Services, a.DeviceID
order by COUNT(b.Hostname)desc;

Comment: there is no results prompted

Comment: Please edit your question to add some example data if you want to know why you aren't getting the results you expect.

Comment: @kfinity I was getting an error " Unknown column 'b.Hostname' in 'on clause'" , but after GordonLinoff comment I did few changes, but it yet to appear the same with no errors without  getting any result(output) is blank

Comment: Select a.LocationID, a.Model, a.SerialNum,a.Purpose, b.IP, a.Services,a.DeviceID, Count(a.Hostname)

FROM RefConnection.Equipment_Info a JOIN
     RefConnection.Connections b
     ON b.Hostname = a.Hostname AND
        b.status = a.Status JOIN
     RefConnection.VM_Info c
     ON a.Hostname = c.Hostname AND
        a.status = c.Status

group by a.LocationID, a.Model, a.SerialNum, a.Purpose, b.IP, a.Services, a.DeviceID
order by COUNT(b.Hostname)desc;

Comment: @jegash . . . This addresses the question that you asked here, which is about a syntax error caused by scoping rules based on the comma in the `FROM` clause.  If you have another question, it should be asked as a *new* question.